# Error while making timer using python ( invalid literal for int() with base 10 )

Tags: python, time, python-os

I was trying to make a timer using python but when i run that code i get stuck with it  .

This is my code.

```
import os
import time

while True:
    timer = input("enter the time when to stop the timer =  ")
    if "second" in timer or "seconds"in timer:
        t= timer.replace("second","").replace("seconds","")
    elif "minutes" in timer or "minute" in timer:
        t=timer.replace("minutes",'*60').replace("minute",'*60')
    elif "hour" in timer or "hours" in timer:
        t= timer.replace("hour","*60*60").replace("hours","60*60")
    elif "hour" in timer or "hours" in timer and "minutes" in timer or "minute" in timer:
        t=timer.replace("hour","*60*60").replace("hours","60*60").replace("and","+").replace("minutes","*60").replace("minute","*60")
    else:
        print("write valid number")

    when_to_stop =abs(int(t))
    while when_to_stop >0:
        os.system('cls')
        m,s = divmod(when_to_stop,60)
        h,m = divmod(m,60)
        print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
        print("\t\t\t\t|"+str(h).zfill(2)+":" + str(m).zfill(2)+":"+str(s).zfill(2)+"|")
        time.sleep(1)
        when_to_stop -=1
        print()
    print("\t\t\t\tTIME OUT")
    exit()
```

when i run it with giving the value `10 minutes` it shows the error and this code run properly only when i use `10 second`.

```
enter the time when to stop the timer =  10 minutes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\mycodes\python codes\testcode.py", line 35, in <module>
    when_to_stop =abs(int(t))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10 *60'
```

please solve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem of my code but i have still a problem.
when i run the code by giving the value of    `1 hour and 15 minute` it start with wrong time else it work fine .

```
import os
import time
import re
while True:
    timer = input("enter the time when to stop the timer =  ")
    if "second" in timer or "seconds"in timer:
        filtering = re.findall(r'\d+', timer)
        timer = int(''.join(filtering))
    elif "minutes" in timer or "minute" in timer:
        filtering = re.findall(r'\d+', timer)
        timer = int(''.join(filtering))*60
    elif "hour" in timer or "hours" in timer:
        filtering = re.findall(r'\d+', timer)
        timer = int(''.join(filtering))*3600
    elif "hour" in timer or "hours" in timer and "minutes" in timer or "minute" in timer:
        filtering = re.findall(r'\d+', timer)
        a=(int(''.join(filtering[0]))*3600)
        b=(int(''.join(filtering[1]))*60)
        timer =a+b
    else:
        print("Please! write valid number")

    when_to_stop =abs(int(timer))
    while when_to_stop >0:
        os.system('cls')
        m,s = divmod(when_to_stop,60)
        h,m = divmod(m,60)
        print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
        print("\t\t\t\t|"+str(h).zfill(2)+":" + str(m).zfill(2)+":"+str(s).zfill(2)+"|")
        time.sleep(1)
        when_to_stop -=1
        print()
    print("\t\t\t\tTIME OUT")
    exit()
```

Comment: I did a little testing and there is an issue with the structure of your code. Since you have an if statement checking for 'minutes' before 'hours' if you have anything like 1 hour 15 minutes it will trigger the first conditional before the hours and minutes (last) conditionals.

Comment: I updated my code above with a fix. It should work without errors now.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to convert the '10 *60' string to an integer. If you place print(t) inside of every condition for testing you can see that when the code gets to:

when_to_stop =abs(int(t))

t is equal to a string that cannot be converted to an integer.

Instead of using replace, you can simply keep the conditional structure but then strip the string to just the integer and multiply it as necessary.

```
import re
timer = input("enter the time when to stop the timer =  ")
    if "second" in timer or "seconds"in timer:
        t = re.findall(r'\d+', timer)  # this returns a list containing the integer like so ['10'] for '10 seconds'
```

Here is the full part of your first loop:

```
    while True:
        timer = input("enter the time when to stop the timer =  ")
        if "second" in timer or "seconds"in timer:
            t = re.findall(r'\d+', timer)
            totalTime = t[0]
        elif "minutes" in timer or "minute" in timer:
            t = re.findall(r'\d+', timer)
            totalTime = t[0] * 60
        elif "hour" in timer or "hours" in timer:
            t = re.findall(r'\d+', timer)
            totalTime = t[0] * 60 * 60
        elif "hour" in timer or "hours" in timer and "minutes" in timer or "minute" in timer:
            t = re.findall(r'\d+', timer)
            totalTime = (t[0] * 60 * 60) + (t[1] * 60)

        else:
            print("write valid number")
```

totalTime will therefore be the total time in seconds. I ran this and it works but displaying the time in hours is not working but minutes and seconds are. This is a separate issue of how you are processing the totalTime seconds to display the counter counting down.

According to the tests I ran this code should be fully functional - let me know if it doesn't work for you.

```
import os
import time
import re


while True:
    timer = input("enter the time when to stop the timer =  ")
    if "second" in timer or "seconds"in timer:
        filtering = re.findall(r'\d+', timer)
        timer = int(''.join(filtering))
    elif ('minutes' not in timer and "minute" not in timer) and ("hour" in timer or "hours" in timer):
        filtering = re.findall(r'\d+', timer)
        timer = int(''.join(filtering))*3600
    elif ("hour" in timer or "hours" in timer) and ("minutes" in timer or "minute" in timer):
        print('hello')
        filtering = re.findall(r'\d+', timer)
        a=(int(''.join(filtering[0]))*3600)
        b=(int(''.join(filtering[1]))*60)
        timer =a+b
    elif "minutes" in timer or "minute" in timer:
        filtering = re.findall(r'\d+', timer)
        timer = int(''.join(filtering))*60
    else:
        print("Please! write valid number")

    when_to_stop =abs(int(timer))
    while when_to_stop >0:
        os.system('cls')
        m,s = divmod(when_to_stop,60)
        h,m = divmod(m,60)
        print("\t\t\t\t|"+str(h).zfill(2)+":" + str(m).zfill(2)+":"+str(s).zfill(2)+"|")
        time.sleep(1)
        when_to_stop -=1
        print()
    print("\t\t\t\tTIME OUT")
    exit()
```

Comment: i am still stucked it dont multiple it just print 60 times

Comment: I updated my answer above to reflect what I was trying to show -- I tested it and this code works. Only issue is how you are displaying the time when it is counting down.

Comment: if you are reeading @Timothee Legros please respond to the past which i have posted below as answer